# Chat integration to existing Spring based application [Web + Mobile]

Tags: node.js, spring-mvc, socket.io, spring-websocket

We are having existing Web application in Spring MVC. We are using Tomcat server. Also we have mobile app [Androis and iOs] for the same which is using spring based rest services. Now, we want to integrate **chat functionality** to both mobile and web application. I came across **Socket.io** and **Node.js**, which seems good. But, I am not much aware of these two frameworks. Then I came to know about **Spring WebSocket**.

> Few Questions :

1. Which way is better to implement chat for existing spring based web
   and mobile applications ? - Spring Websocket / Socket.io - Node.js
2. If we are going with Socket.io and Node.js, then how could I
   configure the node.js to listen to my existing tomcat server port ?
   Or I need to use separate port for client server communication for
   chat functionality. [Because I tried to use same port, it was giving
   **Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::9090**]

Any example would be the great help.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample  application that sends messages back and forth,

Socket.io is used on client side to subscribe to a Topic of the server side.

Similarly you can use Sock.js with stomp client at client side and Spring on server side which provides an easy configuration with STOMP and also message handler annotation such as

@MessageMapping annotation which ensures that if a message is sent to destination mapping say "/hello" then the method associated with it should be called.

@SendTo annotation which is used to specify the value on which the returned message will be broadcast.

[#Example stomp with spring for sending messages.](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Vipul. But, I have started using nodejs and socket.io for implementing as I found it easy as compared to Spring websocket.